# jquery javascript .prop("checked") on checkbox returns undefined for checked checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

To begin I use prop("checked") in stead of attr("checked") because as if I understand it, the prop is used to retrieve wether te checkbox is checked or not, and the attr only tells you wether the html attribute is set or not (like in the initial html code).

Now I have two checkboxes written out in php like this:

```
echo '<h4>Special</h4>';
$specials=array('Is Home Page', 'Does not appear in navigation');
for($i=0;$i<count($specials);++$i){
if($specials[$i]!=''){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="special[',$i,']"';
    if($page['special']&pow(2,$i))
        echo ' checked="checked"';
    echo ' />',$specials[$i],'<br />';
}
}
```

Which results in elements :

```
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"special[0]​"/>​
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"special[1]​"/>​
```

when I check one of the checkboxes I want to retrieve the value to send to the server but this does not seem to work:

```
var $home = $("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special[0]']");
//if($home.is(":checked")){ // always returns false
if($home.prop("checked")){  // always returns undefined
 special["0"] = "Home";
}
var $hidden = $("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special[1]']");
//if($hidden.is(":checked")){ // always returns false
if($hidden.prop("checked")){ // always returns undefined
 special["1"] = "isHidden";
}
```

As pointed out in the comment of the code, the prop("checked"), always returns undefined.
I now the checkboxes are checked ...
Also I have tried with the is(":checked"), but that always returns false.
There is only one dom element selected each time (I know the .prop() only works for the first in the set)

Any ideas are appreciated!

The selector is correct as I have tested it in the console and it returns the correct result (with and without the backslashes-:

```
$("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special\\[1\\]']")
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"special[1]​">​

$("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special\\[0\\]']")
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"special[0]​">​

$("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special[1]']")
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"special[1]​">​

$("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special[0]']")
<input type=​"checkbox" name=​"special[0]​">​
```

I have used jQuery version

i'm using jquery 1.9.0:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Regards!

Comment: What's the version of jQuery are you using??

Comment: does `$home` has any element?

Comment: @ruben056 A jsfiddle will be better.

Comment: Put your `generated` HTML code too :)

Answer (score 4):

Per the [JQuery documention](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you have to escape the square brackets.

```
var $home = $("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special\\[0\\]']");
//if($home.is(":checked")){ // always returns false
if($home.prop("checked")){  // always returns undefined
     special["0"] = "Home";
}
var $hidden = $("#tabs-advanced-options input[name='special\\[1\\]']");
//if($hidden.is(":checked")){ // always returns false
if($hidden.prop("checked")){ // always returns undefined
    special["1"] = "isHidden";
}
```

Comment: I have added the backslashes but to no avail. Also I have checked the $home and the $hidden and they do contain the correct input element!

Comment: what's the value of $home.length or $hidden.length? if they're zero then that means the selector has no elements associated.

Comment: length is 1, also i have extended the initial questions with some selector results in the browser console which return the correct element

Comment: please create a JsFiddle of your problem. As you can see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cmrar/) works fine.

Comment: Allright i have found the issue. When dynamically filling the content of the form, i used the removeProp("checked") operation in stead of the prop("checked",false). Now all is working fine